# Send POST request to server, Server's response is null, Angular - Spring-boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http, angular-httpclient

I want to send a POST request with my angular client to my spring-boot server.

The server receive sucessfully the data and anwser with 200 Code and body with a string that contains "ok".

But the client receive null as anwser.

Angular code :

```js
httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET'
        })
    };
```

```js
this.http.post(this.URL, JSON.stringify(this.alert), this.httpOptions)
            .subscribe((result: string) => {
                if (result == null || result === 'error') {
                    //if fail;
                } else {
                    //if success;
                }
                console.log('result :' + result);
            })
```

Spring-boot code :

```java
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
    @PostMapping(value = "/url")
    public ResponseEntity objDataController(@RequestBody ObjData objData) {
        HttpHeaders resHeader = new HttpHeaders();

        resHeader.set("origin", "http://localhost:8080");
        resHeader.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        resHeader.set("Accept", "application/json");

        //some code

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(resHeader)
                .body("ok");
    }
```

At console.log get : 
`result :null`

Thanks

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the actual request (network tab of browsers console). Is everything running on localhost? It could be some cors problems, caused by a failing preflight request.

Comment: Have you looked at the response in f12 console?

Comment: @marcel Yes, server and client are in localhost, that's why i used ```@CrossOrigin``` on spring-boot

Comment: @JensAlenius yes, the response said ```result :null```

Comment: in Angular the subscribe method callback is first success then error. So HttpClient is handling it as a success. ex: .subscribe(successCallback,failureCallback) and the success is called as we can see in your console. I think the body might be null. Have you checked the responsebody in f12?

Comment: I am no expert in spring boot and I don't know what exactly `@CrossOrigin` does, but did you still look in the browsers console (f12, network tab) that this is the correct request (with POST) and not a preflight (with OPTION)? because normally with your setting (port != 80 and specific headers set in request) the browser would automatically make a preflight request

Comment: @JensAlenius I print the response created on subscribe, this is not the responsebody ?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of your network request and response so that's it will be easy to figure out

Comment: By looking at the network response in f12 we can see if the server is returning the body in the response. Its just a matter of narrowing down the problem

Comment: Ok, I looked at f12 network tab, and the body of the anwser is not null, (equals to "ok"), I guess then the problem is my angular function

Comment: Weird. Try adding the generic arguments for the post method. <any> should do. Are you using the latest httpclient? (angular 5 and upward)

Comment: @JensAlenius I try to add <any>, it's doesn't work, and i'm using angular 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fix my problem, I change this:

```java
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(resHeader)
                .body("ok");
```

By:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(resHeader)
                .body(gson.toJson("ok", String.class));
```

Thanks you for your anwsers !

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and it helped specifying the response-type:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
this.httpClient.delete(url, {headers: headers, responseType: 'text'});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess it won't help me, I use POST instead of DELETE and my problem is with the ```.subscribe```

Comment: might still be worth a try. What do you mean by 'my problem is with the subscribe'? Cause if your httpClient tries to interpret the 'OK' string as JSON it will not return the string...

Answer (score 0):

It's the chrome console messing with you, when it comes to observables, it can't interpret the value correctly. I guess if you use the result inside the 'If success' block, it is bound to work